# SMTPRecipientsRefused in Django send email

Tags: django

I'm trying to send email thru my Django app. I have this in my `local_settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'support@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myPassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I have this in my `views.py`:

```
send_mail(
    subject="Subject here",
    message="Hello.",
    from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    recipient_list=["someone@gmail.com],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

But when the `send_mail()` executes, I get this error:

```
{u'someone@gmail.com': (504, '5.5.2 <webmaster@localhost>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address')}
```

Why? And how do I make my app send emails properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that it needs a fully qualified address. Basically, the domain part should be a fully qualified domain name, like `mydomain.com`, whereas you are using `localhost`.

Send the email from your actual domain address and it should be accepted.

---

One more thing. You will also need to authenticate your domain name so that Gmail knows you actually own it. Otherwise Gmail will either mark emails sent by your domain as spam or will just blacklist you and reject all mails from your domain.

Domain authentication is a rather vast topic. Gmail has published some guidelines about sending mail which is a good starting point. See the [Authentication & Identification](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication) section to find out more.

Comment: In my case, my code will send to one email address.

Comment: @Username Still need to authenticate your domain by setting up SPF and DKIM records so as to not get blacklisted or marked as spammed.

Answer (score 0):

there's missing quote

```
send_mail(
    subject="Subject here",
    message="Hello.",
    from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    recipient_list=["someone@gmail.com"], # <---
    fail_silently=False, 
 )
```

and make sure you are using real domain in `EMAIL_HOST_USER`

Comment: What goes there? An empty string? Can you edit to show me?

Answer (score 0):

Change The Tls setings to EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
Private mail only supports SSl